# Are these two SQL queries the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is this sql query:

```
update x
        set Amount = Amount * -1
from XTable x
        join WTable w ON w.ID = x.id
        join YTable y ON y.id = x.id
where y.negative = 1
    
update x
        set Amount = Amount * -1
from XTable x
        join ZTable z ON z.id = x.id
        join YTable y ON y.id = x.id
where y.negative = 1
```

.... the same as this?

```
update x
    set Amount = Amount * -1
from XTable x
        join WTable w ON ON w.id = x.id
        join YTable y ON y.id = x.id
    Full Outer Join ZTable z ON z.id = x.id
where y.negative = 1
```

Will they always return the same table in every single case?

Comment: In theory, a row in x can be updated twice in the first batch - flipping the sign in the first query and then reversing the effect in the second query. That cannot happen with a single query. So technically, the answer is NO. Your usage may prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed they are... `full join` operates over the join between `x`, `y` and `w`. So it gets this subset, plus `z`, with all the records from this table, joined or not. After, the `y.negative =  1` filter applies on the full data set, so all records from `z` not joined are rejected because they have a `y.negative = null`.

I would use this one to do it with just one query, however, just for a better understanding (and probably performs better than `full join`):

```
update x
  set Amount = Amount * -1
from XTable x
  join YTable y ON y.id = x.id
  left join WTable w ON w.ID = x.id
  left join ZTable z ON z.id = x.id         
where y.negative = 1
  and (z.id is not null or w.id is not null) -- non sargable version --> isnull(z.id, w.id) is not null
```

This way you filter `y.negative = 1` and update `x` just when `w` or `z` are joined (maybe some `y.negative = 1` has a `null,null` for these tables...)

Comment: `WHERE z.id IS NOT NULL OR w.id IS NOT NULL` would be better, as it's SARGable.

Comment: Changed, thanks @Larnu

Comment: No they aren't the same: the version with two queries requires `z` to be joined to `x` and `y` as well, whereas the `full join` version does not

Comment: @Charlieface, the filter by `y.negative = 1`  is the trick on all of this. The joins with other tables are meaningless (they act as an `exists`), because at the end all the records will be filtered based on `y.negative = 1` or not.

Comment: Good point, `y` is effectively inner joined, but `x` is not

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same.

In a simplified test there are differences in the result.

**A) the first (2 updates)**

| id | Amount | negative | x | w | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | True | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | False | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | *null* | 3 | 3 | *null* | *null* |
| 4 | 2 | True | 4 | *null* | 4 | *null* |
| 5 | 2 | *null* | 5 | *null* | *null* | 5 |
| 6 | -3 | True | 6 | 6 | 6 | *null* |
| 7 | -3 | True | 7 | *null* | 7 | 7 |
| 9 | 1 | *null* | 9 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

**B) the second (single update)**

| id | Amount | negative | x | w | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -4 | True | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | False | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | *null* | 3 | 3 | *null* | *null* |
| 4 | 2 | True | 4 | *null* | 4 | *null* |
| 5 | 2 | *null* | 5 | *null* | *null* | 5 |
| 6 | -3 | True | 6 | 6 | 6 | *null* |
| 7 | 3 | True | 7 | *null* | 7 | 7 |
| 9 | 1 | *null* | 9 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

So there's a difference in id 1 & 7

Here's a single update that gives the same results as the first double update.

> ```
> -- Extra
> update x
>     set Amount = Amount * -1
> from XTable x
> join YTable y ON y.id = x.id and y.negative = 1
> left join  WTable w ON w.id = x.id
> left join  ZTable z ON z.id = x.id 
> where ((w.id is null and z.id is not null)
>     or (w.id is not null and z.id is null))
> ```

But I assume you want something like this

> ```
> -- Extra 2
> update x
>     set Amount = Amount * -1
> from XTable x
> join YTable y ON y.id = x.id and y.negative = 1
> left join  WTable w ON w.id = x.id
> left join  ZTable z ON z.id = x.id 
> where (w.id is not null or z.id is not null)
> ```

| id | Amount | negative | x | w | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -4 | True | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | False | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | *null* | 3 | 3 | *null* | *null* |
| 4 | 2 | True | 4 | *null* | 4 | *null* |
| 5 | 2 | *null* | 5 | *null* | *null* | 5 |
| 6 | -3 | True | 6 | 6 | 6 | *null* |
| 7 | -3 | True | 7 | *null* | 7 | 7 |
| 9 | 1 | *null* | 9 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=44558058dc553469f71c8c15e2eed4fa)*